# Find limit of a random variable: $\lim_\limits{s\to\infty} s^n P(|Y| > s)$.

Tags: calculus, probability, limits, probability-distributions, random-variables

$Y$ is a random variable such that ${E[|Y|^n]}<\infty$ for $n>0$.

Find $\lim_\limits{s\to\infty} s^n P(|Y| > s)$.

The answer key gives the answer $0$ without any explanation. I would assume this involves the use of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and the fact that $E[Y^p]=\int p \, t^{p-1} \, S_x \,\mathrm{d}t$, $S_x$ being the survivor function. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: You mean $E[Y^n] < \infty$ for all $n > 0$?

Comment: no what i typed is the question thats why i am a little confused as I can't apply E[Y^p] here

Comment: Let $Y$ be a positive r.v. with pdf $C x^{-3}$ on $[1,\infty)$.  Then the CDF is of degree $-2$.  For $n$ sufficiently large, the limit is undefined.

Answer (score 4):

Write

$$s^n \mathbb{P}(|Y|>s) = \int_{\{|Y|>s\}} s^n \, d\mathbb{P}$$

to conclude that

$$s^n \mathbb{P}(|Y|>s) \leq \int_{\{|Y|>s\}} |Y|^n \, d\mathbb{P}.$$

Apply a convergence theorem of your choice to show that the right-hand side converges to $0$ as $s \to \infty$:

Comment: what does this have to do with $E(Y^n)<\infty$? also, can you suggest one convergence theorem i can use to apply to he second eq? thanks

Comment: @jamesblack $\mathbb{E}(|Y|^n)<\infty$ is needed to apply the convergence theorem. And no, I'm not going to give you a further hint unless you show some effort. How long have you thought about my answer? For 1 minute or 2 perhaps?

Comment: From OP's response to my 1st comment, it seems that only $E[Y]$ is finite.  (not even $E[|Y|]$)

Comment: sorry i doubel checked its actually a abs value sign so you were right thanks

Comment: doest $ \int_{\{|Y|>s\}} |Y|^n \, d\mathbb{P}=$|Y|^n*P(|Y|>s)=0$$?

Comment: @jamesblack No, this doesn't hold true. You might want to apply the dominated convergence theorem, yes? For this you have to find an integrable dominating function for $$1_{\{|Y|>s\}} |Y|^n$$

Comment: @GNUSupporter see the OPs comment to your comment. If $\mathbb{E}(|Y|^n)$ was infinite, one could easily construct counterexamples to the assertion.

Comment: $\int_{\{|Y|>s\}} |Y|^n \, d\mathbb{P}$ has to equal to integral of f and we can set f=0 here? and g(y)=|y|^n? then using that Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem theorem, we can show its zero?

Comment: I upvoted after OP's edit, which makes things clear.  OP's initial response to my question is not the same as to yours.

Comment: @jamesblack Not sure what $f$ and $g$ you are talking about. Perhaps it would be a good idea to take a look at the dominated convergence theorem and to get a better understanding of its assumptions before you attempt to solve this question. The first step to apply the dominated convergence is clearly to identify all the ingredients which appear in the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: i used the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem#Dominated_convergence_in_Lp-spaces_(corollary) and the first theorem is Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem where i need to find g and f

Comment: @jamesblack I see; well, yes, $f=0$ and $g=|Y|^n$.

Comment: so what I had should be alright? my confusion is if i define g that way, then g is not really a function is it? since g still depends on n, so it is sort of like the $f_n$ bounded by g where $f_n<g$

Comment: @jamesblack You are confusing some things. 1) Your problem involves a number $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (which is fixed) and so you should use $n$ as an index. So let's say you have a sequence $(f_k)_k$. In your problem, $$f_k(\omega) = 1_{\{|Y(\omega)|>k\}} |Y(\omega)|^n$$ and you want to let $k \to \infty$ (again: $n$ is fixed!). 2) $g$ **is** a random variable and hence a function. Note that we are working on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$ (this is the measure space which is mentioned in the dominated convergence theorem).

Comment: In particular, $g(\omega) = |Y(\omega)|^n$ is a mapping $g:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$.